# tipauni: overwriting textipa macro applies to accented characters not written inside textipa

Tags: tipauni

I would like to modify the `\textipa` command provided by the `tipauni` package. For instance, suppose I always want to put square brackets around IPA characters:

```
\let\oldtextipa\textipa
\renewcommand{\textipa}[1]{\oldtextipa{[\textipa{#1}]}}
```

I realize this usage isn't a great idea; my actual use case is to write IPA symbols in a separate font by making `\textipa` automatically switch the font. This seems to help some of my students remember the difference between IPA and English orthography, even though there is overlap in the symbols. However, adding the font packages would make the MWE less than minimal, so I've avoided it here to just focus on the root of the issue.

The problem is made apparent when typing accented characters using LaTeX shortcuts: `\"u` gets square brackets around it. Unicode characters (i.e., directly entering `ü`) are not affected. `\"uü` now produces the following, for instance:

[image]

Interestingly, this doesn't happen when using `tipa`, just `tipauni` (though of course, the advantages of having unicode output make me prefer `tipauni`). Why is the `\textipa` redefinition affecting characters not written inside `\textipa`? Is there a way to fix this without renaming the `\textipa` macro? I'd like to keep it the same if the fix is easy, since it'll be consistent and easier to remember that way.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[preservefont]{tipauni}
\let\oldtextipa\textipa
\renewcommand{\textipa}[1]{\oldtextipa{[{#1}]}}

\begin{document}
    \"uü
\end{document}
```

Comment: the tipauni package is using \textipa internally a lot, and redefining it is really not a great idea. Instead of patching around, better ask the maintainer for a proper interface for whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe the way to go is just changing the new macro to a different name like `\mytextipa` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

With or without your redefinition you get, in succession

```
\TU-cmd \"\TU\" u

\tipauniumlaut u

\@ifstar{\TipaUniSubUmlaut}{\TipaUniSupUmlaut}u

\TipaUniSupUmlaut u

\textsupumlaut{\textipa{#1}}
```

and now you can see where your redefinition fails, because `\textsupumlaut` is defined by

```
\DeclareUnicodeAccent{\textsupumlaut}{TU}{"0308}%% ̈
```

so what you essentially get is

```
[u]^^^^0308
```

with `[u]` in the IPA font and the accent is placed with respect to the square bracket rather than the `u`.

I can't see any way to get what you want via a redefinition of `\textipa`.

Just my opinion, but

```
[\"u]
```

is *much* easier and clearer.

Comment: I agree `[\"u]` is much better for this case, and wouldn't bother doing it this way. The actual thing I want to do is something like `\newfontfamily{\ipafont}{DoulosSIL}`, `\let\oldtextipa\textipa`, and then `\renewcommand{\textipa}[1]{\oldtextipa{\ipafont{#1}}`. Having the IPA symbols in a different font seems to help my students remember that, e.g., r and ɹ are different. The problem is that when I do that, it changes the font of the accented characters _outside_ the `textipa` macro (e.g., in glossed examples). But I wanted to avoid the complication of adding the font packages to the MWE.